# https for secure data transfer between as3 and php

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, encryption, https

I need to transfer data from a flash application running in a browser to a server running php.  If I use an https connection will that be enough to ensure that the data sent from flash to the server is encrypted and sensitive data can't be sniffed, or do I need to do encryption in my flash application itself?

Comment: I am no expert on the subject but from what I understand HTTPs is definitely a must and can be sufficient for most web servers, along with security's best practices of course. How sensitive is your data?

Comment: It is extremely sensitive data.  I have seen some home brewed libraries on the net, and I can't rely on using these.  I'm hoping that https will do the trick, but I'd like to know if there's something I'm overlooking before I start implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the HTTPS protocol will encrypt data between the users' computer and your server.

If you are only worried about the transport of your data, and you can assume that the attacker does not have access to the private keys used to encrypt the SSL request, then you are fine using HTTPS.

Home-brewed encryption could provide an additional layer of protection.  Even if an attacker does manage to get your SSL certificates, they would also have to crack your home-brewed encryption to understand the data.

If HTTPS is unavailable, home-brewed encryption can still get you some level of security.  The downside is that any attacker can decompile your SWF and analyze your encryption algorithm to potentially build a decryption tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I guess I will rely on the magic of https to do the grunt work for me.  I think I am still going to do a home brewed encryption too, just to be on the safer side (I know there is no 100% hacker safe way).